# User Defined Functions and Aggregate in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am testing the UDF / UDA feature in Cassandra, It seems good. But I have few questions in using it.

1) In the Cassandra.yaml, It is mentioned that sandboxing is enabled for avoiding the evil code, So are we violating the rule and what will be the consequences of enabling this support (flag)?

2) What are the advantages of using UDF / UDA in Cassandra compared to reading the data and writing the aggregation logic in client side?

3) Also, apart from JAVA, Is there a language support available for nodejs, python in writing UDF / UDA?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some comments:

1. Sandboxing prevents execution of "dangerous" code - working with files/sockets, starting threads, etc.   [This blog post](https://hardcodejavadog.blogspot.de/2015/10/user-defined-functions-in-apache.html) provides some additional details about it.
2. It could be several - you don't move data from coordinator node to your app, you offload calculations to cassandra cluster, etc.
3. Languages supporting [JSR 223 "Scripting for Java"](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223) - JavaScript, Groovy, JRuby, Jython, ... (with `enable_scripted_user_defined_functions` set to true in Cassandra config).  But Java should be the fastest.

Also look to [this presentation about UDF/UDA](https://www.slideshare.net/RobertStupp/user-definedfunctionscassandrasummiteu2014) from author of this functionality (Robert Stupp) & [this blog post](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1876) with more details & examples.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Could you please check this, I posted one more question regarding the aggregation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709008/aggregation-in-cassandra-across-partitions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710070/sum-aggregation-for-each-columns-in-cassandra

Comment: I'll look when have a time (I'm really subscribed to cassandra questions, so I've got your questions in my list already)

Comment: Thats Great, Thanks Alex, I need your opinion for this design question, I will be expecting your response every second. Thanks again :)

Comment: Another piece of cake for you Alex : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977824/understanding-read-from-a-single-partition-in-cassandra Can you please check and respond to this